# Can Visual Studio 2019 Community be installed on WIndows Server 2016 Core?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, docker, xamarin.forms, devops

Can I silently install Visual Studio 2019 Community on a Windows 2016 Core docker container?  I've followed the instructions to download the VS Community exe then extract to a vslayout folder.  I copied this folder to my Windows 2016 Server core docker container during build and I try to run the install using:

```
RUN .\vs_setup.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat --includeRecommended --quiet --norestart
```

During the build I get a couple of lines like the following and the last one being:

```
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e1ab6aced6786d403760\vRemoving intermediate container 67a8e8bebba1
```

Then the rest of the container build continues and finishes with no errors but you can tell none of the cross platform libraries were installed, not to mention the installed completed too fast anyway so it's no suprise.

Am I wasting my time? Is it even possible to do this in windows container?  I just want to be able to build my xamarin.android apps in a windows server 2016 core build agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  (I assume) you have to use Visual Studio Build Tools.  For help on how to set it up just go to docker hub and find the microsoft .net framework sdk windows image and look at the dockerfile.  You'll see how they setup the build tools.  Then Google the term `visual studio build tools workloads` to find whatever build components you want to add.

Based on the Microsoft dockerfile, here is my relevant edited part that got me going with android development:

```
&& setx /M DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE 1 `
&& start /w vs_BuildTools.exe ^ `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools ^ `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools ^ `
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK ^ `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.XamarinBuildTools;includeOptional ^ `
    --quiet --norestart --nocache --wait `
&& powershell -Command "if ($err = dir $Env:TEMP -Filter dd_setup_*_errors.log | where Length -gt 0 | Get-Content) { throw $err }" `
&& del vs_BuildTools.exe `
```